# Styling a TextField GXT 3

Tags: java, css, gxt, appearance

I want to set the text-size property of a gxt TextField. 
I start from writing MyTextFieldAppearance. Here is everything ok.
Next i need to modify my.gwt.xml file, and here I get into trouble.

There is no TextFieldAppearance in class `com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.TextField`,
the only TextFieldAppearance is in class TextInputCell.TextFieldAppearance, but if I write

```
<replace-with
  class="ru.nicetu.radient.kef.client.appearance.KefValueBaseFieldAppearance">
  <when-type-is
    class="com.sencha.gxt.cell.core.client.form.TextInputCell.TextFieldAppearance" />
</replace-with>
```

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in gxt, in method

```
  public TextFieldDefaultAppearance(TextFieldResources resources) {
    super(resources);
    this.resources = resources;
    this.style = this.resources.css();
  }
```

you need to add line

```
  StyleInjectorHelper.ensureInjected(this.style, true);
```

to the end